# how to mix two digits from URL php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two variables from URL.

ie, `$_GET["pro_id"]` and `$_GET["pro_page"]` and

`$_GET["pro_id"] = 1,2,3,4,` and
`$_GET["pro_page"] = 1,1,1,3,`

I have separated these variables as

```
$pro_id = $_GET["pro_id"];
$pro_id = explode(",", $pro_id);

foreach($pro_id as $key) {    
    echo $key.'<br/>';    
}

$pro_page = $_GET["pro_page"];
$pro_page = explode(",", $pro_page);

foreach($pro_page as $key) {    
    echo $key.'<br/>';    
}
```

and the output for pro_id is
    1
    2
    3
    4
and for pro_page is
    1
    1
    1
    3

and I want to mix the first digit from pro_id and first digit from pro_page.
ie,

```
select * from db_table where row1=1 and row2=1
select * from db_table where row1=2 and row2=1
select * from db_table where row1=3 and row2=1
select * from db_table where row1=4 and row2=3
```

how to achieve this. Is there any solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "mixing" those numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more reliable, use foreach

```
foreach($propage as $key => $value)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE row1 = '".$pro_id[$key]."' AND row2='".$propage[$key]."'";
}
```

Comment: The given digit is not constant. It will change.

Comment: @JithinVarghese I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you although those are some strange `$_GET` parameters.

```
$pro_id = $_GET["pro_id"];
$pro_id = explode(",", $pro_id);

$pro_page = $_GET["pro_page"];
$pro_page = explode(",", $pro_page);

foreach($pro_id as $idx => $value) {  
    $proid = $value;
    $propage = $pro_page[$idx];  

    //QUERY HERE
    echo $proid." ".$proage; 
}
```

Comment: Now the output is 4 15 16 13 3. I want 41 51 61 33